# Remove the line separator between the buttons and the content in a jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-dialog

I have a jQuery dialog where buttons are separated from content by a solid line. Is it possible to remove this line? I didn't find a way to do this.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Caught with `Firebug` :

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane { border-width: 0 !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I noticed that I need to apply the !important on the css attribute (border-width: 0;) to get it to work. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Old question, late comment: avoid using `!important` as much as possible. Try using css specificity [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity] and make sure your CSS sheet is referenced after the `jquery-ui.css` style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Try the css:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
    border-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the class `.ui-widget-content` and remove the `border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;` . but doing this will remove the border from the entire class and it may effect on other elements where class `.ui-widget-content` is applying so it is better to remove the class from the element from where you want to remove the border itself and write custom css rules as per your requirement.